Code Coverage still 0% in sonarQube for golang
After build my sonarQube dashboard code is showing 0% . How to fix the issue?
sonar.projectKey=nds-nano-svc-register-pengajuan
sonar.projectName=Nds - Nano - Svc - Register - Pengajuan

sonar.sources=.
sonar.test.exclusions=**/proto/**, **/*mock.js, **/*.php, **/config/**, **/model/**, **/container/**, **/util/**, **/mocks/**, **/module/**, **/*_test.go
sonar.go.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.out

My sonarqube dashboard covered my code at leas the percentage is on.

Are you even running tests? what do you have for sonar.tests (should be sonar.tests=. if your sonar.sources is correct, and based on my understanding, you'd also need to add the sonar.test.inclusions=**/*_test.go line
